# Galois fixed part of modules. Why does $|(1-\sigma)A||A^G|=|A|$ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-cohomology, fixed-points, galois-cohomology

Let $L/K$ be a quadratic extension of number field $K$.
Let $\sigma$ be a generator of $G=Gal(L/K)$.

Let $A$ be a finite $Gal(L/K)$ module.

Then,

> Why does $|(1-\sigma)A||A^G|=|A|$ hold ?

Here, $|A|$ means order of $A$.
I'm having difficulty to relate $A^G$ with $(1-\sigma)A$.I'm even beginning to think that this equation may not hold unless some additional structure is imposed on A.

Any hints or reference is also appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does $|A|$ mean? Usually it denotes cardinality, but is a bit odd to ask about cardinalities of possibly infinite abelian groups (cardinal arithmetic is "boring" here). Or are you assuming that $A$ is finite?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Sorry, A is finite and it is the order of A.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fixed points $A^G$ are exactly the elements of $A$ that are annihilated by $1-\sigma$ (since they are the elements $a\in A$ such that $\sigma(a)=a$).  So, there is a short exact sequence $$0\to A^G\to A\stackrel{1-\sigma}\to (1-\sigma)A\to 0$$ from which your cardinality equation follows.